# Set binding in object initializer expression

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

For adding some images to a WrapPanel, I'm trying to iterate through a collection. My TileCollection contains instances of a Tile class which has a ImageSource property.

I've got it by doing all the stuff step by step - Create a new image 1, assign all the properties, create a bew binding 1, assign binding 1 to image 1, add image 1 to the panel, proceed with image 2, ... tons of code I want to shorten now. Here is what I've got so far:

```
For Each tile As Tile In TileCollection
     MainPanel.Children.Add(New Image With {.Width = 80, .Height = 80, .Margin = New Thickness(10), .SetBinding = New Binding With {.Source = tile, Path = New PropertyPath("ImageSource"), .Mode = BindingMode.Default, .UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged)}})
Next
```

1) ."SetBinding" doesn't work in object initializer expression. Is there any workaround?

2) Is there any way to add a handler in object initializer expression, for e.g. capturing mousedown events?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create extension methods on the objects that you need that do what you want and then return the self instance again to allow chaining, effectively creating a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). You then call these methods after the object initializer expression.